# What is wrong with the .add in my GUI program?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a GUI with a Grid layout that presents 3 random non repeatable cards within a file. I named all the cards 1-53.png and am trying to insert it into the panels of left, center, and right. When I try adding the files into my panels, there is an error withe the .add, and I do not know how to fix it.

I have already tried to change the .add and the index. I even tried to turn the int into a component, but nothing works.

```
public class Question_2 {
    static String location = "cards/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frmMyWindow = new frmMyWindow("Random Cards");
        frmMyWindow.setSize(300, 200);
        frmMyWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frmMyWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmMyWindow.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class frmMyWindow extends JFrame {
    JLabel lblName, l;
    JPanel panelMain, panelLeft, panelCenter, panelRight;
    JFrame f;

    public frmMyWindow(String Cards) {
        super("Random Cards");

        lblName = new JLabel("Cards");
        panelMain = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 10, 10));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 10));
        add(lblName, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelMain, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panelLeft = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 10));
        panelCenter = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        panelRight = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 10));
        panelMain.add(panelLeft);
        panelMain.add(panelCenter);
        panelMain.add(panelRight);

        panelLeft.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Card 1"));
        panelCenter.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Card 2"));
        panelRight.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Card 3"));

        int index = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 53);
        int index2 = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 53);
        int index3 = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 53);
        while (index == index2) {
            index2 = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 53);
        }
        while (index3 == index2 || index3 == index)
            ;
        {
            index3 = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 53);
        }
        String image = index + ".png";
        String image2 = index2 + ".png";
        String image3 = index3 + ".png";

        panelLeft.add(index);

        panelCenter.add(index2);

        panelRight.add(index3);

    }
}
```

I want the program to present 3 random cards into the panels, but there is an error with the .add.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed to the `add` method and how you call it. `Container#add` method takes as arguments `Component`s. You call it with `int` arguments.

> I even tried to turn the int into a component, but nothing works.

The simplest way (I guess) to "add a number in a container" is to create a `JLabel` and add to it the number as text. By seeing your first attempt, I guess that you again messed up the methods. Probably in `JLabel`s constructor. You did something like `new JLabel(index)` where `index` is an Integer. Which again fails because there is no constructor with `int` argument. The solution is to create a `JLabel` AND convert the integer to text:

```
panelLeft.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(index)));
```

After that program can be compiled and run. However some notes are:

1. Always run your application using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` since all Swing applications must run on their own thread.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            JFrame frmMyWindow = new frmMyWindow("Random Cards");
            frmMyWindow.setSize(300, 200);
            frmMyWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frmMyWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frmMyWindow.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
```

2. All class names "should" (well, its the standard convention) start with an Uppercase letter. Rename `frmMyWindow` to `FrmMyWindow`.

Comment: Expansion of the 2nd point. Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: @gpasch The creator of this thing told me. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html